# When user type !verify gets verified role

Tags: discord, discord.js

What i want to happen is when user type command "!verify" i want them to give "Verified" role,
i am currently running the latest Discord.js which is version 12.3.1 based on dependencies.

```
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}verify`)){

        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        var role = guild.roles.cache.find('name', 'Verified');

        member.addrole(role).then((member)=> {
            message.channel.send(":white_check_mark: " + member.displayName + " is now verified!");
        })

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few lines in your code that won't work due to having being deprecated methods.

---

```js
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find('name', 'Verified');

// should be replace with:

var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Verified);
```

and

```js
member.addrole(role).then((member)= > {
    message.channel.send(":white_check_mark: " + member.displayName + " is now verified!");
})

// should be replaced with:

member.roles.cache.add(role)
message.channel.send(":white_check_mark: " + member.displayName + " is now verified!");
```

Comment: await member.roles.cache.add(role)
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: You don't need it, you can just remove the `await`

Comment: missing thing.. then everything works
edit:  message.guild.roles.cache.find